# Responsively Resize Kendo Chart (Typescript, Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui

My intention is to responsively resize a chart in Kendo UI. At the moment, I am testing out the functionality so I wrapped it in an ng-click function.

```
public Click(): void {

    if (typeof this.$scope.overviewPiechart !== 'undefined')
        this.$scope.overviewPiechart.refresh();
}
```

I placed the size information in the k-chart-area directive in the HTML:

```
k-chart-area="{height: {{ KC_PO_PCS.GetChartHeight() }}, width: {{ KC_PO_PCS.GetChartWidth() }}}"
```

The intended output is that the chart will resize to fill the page, but the actual output is that the chart blinks, and then reloads while maintaining the same size.

**I have also tried overviewPiechart.redraw()**

How can I make it so that my chart gets resized?

Comment: Isn't the correct call `resize`? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-resize

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I've spent the past 5 or 6 hours looking at almost everything and studying why 4 or 5 punkrs don't resize. Thanks.

Comment: Moved it to an answer since it worked. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments seeing as how it did work for you:

Isn't the correct call resize? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-resize